# Import Member Group attribute from AD to .csv

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, export, quest

I am using ActiveRoles Management Shell under Windows XP , Powershell ver 2 for retreiving Group data from AD and exporting it to csv file.Everything works well apart from getting member list it is so long that the program is writing in excel cells under member column System.String[] each time.How can I make it write whole list there , is it possible ? I could actually have only the name of the member don't need whole connection path.Is there a possibility to get from group field member only name ?

```
get-QADGroup -SearchRoot 'ou=User,ou=Groups,ou=PL,dc=test,dc=com'| Select-Object -property name,sAMAccountName,description,groupType,member|Export-Csv -path Y:\csv\groups.csv
```

Comment: Do it work with Select-Object -ExpandProperty instead of Select-Object -Property?

Comment: Select-Object : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ExpandProperty'.Specified method is not supported.

Comment: Please provide an example of desired output. Do you want it to output one file for each group, or put all groups into one file?

Comment: I have column group name , group description , group member . In each group member cell I have members of particular group one after another divided by coma for example tomP,andrewN,jessicaR etc.  ( this example is one cell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as Matt suggested you want an expression in your Select statement. I would use something like this:

```
@{l="Members";e={$_.Members -join ", "}}
```

Which when inserted into your one-liner looks like:

```
get-QADGroup -SearchRoot 'ou=User,ou=Groups,ou=PL,dc=test,dc=com'| Select-Object -property name,sAMAccountName,description,groupType,@{l='Members';e={$_.member -join ", "}}|Export-Csv -path Y:\csv\groups.csv -NoTypeInfo
```

I also added -NoTypeInfo to the export to skip the annoying lead line telling you it's a PSCustomObject or some such and actually just get your data (and headers).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to the quest cmdlets so I will provide a solution based on cmdlets from the `activedirectory`

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Employees,DC=Domain,DC=Local" -Properties memberof |
    Select-Object name,@{Name="Groups";Expression={$_.MemberOf | 
    ForEach-Object{(Get-ADGroup -Identity $_).Name + ";"}}} | 
    Export-Csv C:\temp\TEST.CSV -Append
```

To make sense of this by line:

1. Should be self explanatory. Get all users in the OU defined. You would need to change this to suit your needs.
2. The select statement appears normal until you reach the [calculated property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) Groups.
3. What continues from the previous line is cycling through every group that an individual user is a `memberof` and get the friendly name of the group (MemberOf returns `DistinguishedName`'s). At the end of every group add a `";"` as to not interfere with the CSV that will be made later.
4. Append to a csv file.

For brevity I didnt include all the extra properties that you included in your `Select-Object` statement. You would obviously need to add those back as the need fits.

Since you have the use the Quest cmdlets you could just change `member` in your select statement to the following:

```
@{Name="Groups";Expression={$_.member | ForEach-Object{"$_;"}}}
```

I cannot test if this will work. It is based on the assumption that member contains a simple name as supposed to a `distinguishedname`

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use Quest AD shell since I cannot install Active Directory module.

Comment: I made an educated guess on what you would have to change in your select statement to make this logic work. I just cant test the syntax myself to see what the output is like.